# PySide2 Qt Surface Example

Tags: python, c++, pyside2

I would like to reimplement the Qt C++ "[Surface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html)" example (Q3DSurface) in PySide2 but `QSurfaceDataArray` and `QSurfaceDataRow` are not available.

```
void SurfaceGraph::fillSqrtSinProxy()
{
    float stepX = (sampleMax - sampleMin) / float(sampleCountX - 1);
    float stepZ = (sampleMax - sampleMin) / float(sampleCountZ - 1);

    QSurfaceDataArray *dataArray = new QSurfaceDataArray;
    dataArray->reserve(sampleCountZ);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sampleCountZ ; i++) {
        QSurfaceDataRow *newRow = new QSurfaceDataRow(sampleCountX);
        // Keep values within range bounds, since just adding step can cause minor drift due
        // to the rounding errors.
        float z = qMin(sampleMax, (i * stepZ + sampleMin));
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sampleCountX; j++) {
            float x = qMin(sampleMax, (j * stepX + sampleMin));
            float R = qSqrt(z * z + x * x) + 0.01f;
            float y = (qSin(R) / R + 0.24f) * 1.61f;
            (*newRow)[index++].setPosition(QVector3D(x, y, z));
        }
        *dataArray << newRow;
    }

    m_sqrtSinProxy->resetArray(dataArray);
}
```

Is there are way to use a `QVector<QSurfaceDataItem>` in PySide2?

```
from PySide2.QtDataVisualization import QtDataVisualization as QDV

data_item = QDV.QSurfaceDataItem()
data_item.setPosition(QVector3D(x, y, z))
```

The `QSurfaceDataItem` is available but I can't pass the objects to `QSurfaceDataProxy` without `QVector`.

Comment: You could try using PyQt5 instead of PySide2. In PyQt5 you can use a list of lists instead of a `QSurfaeDataArray` but that doesn't seem to work in PySide2.